# Как равномерно выровнять блоки по ширине контейнера Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как равномерно выровнять блоки по ширине контейнера в Bootstrap3 ?
Как такое лучше сделать если блоков к примеру 8шт ? Ведь задаются только целые числа в col-md-*, или же лучше сделать через список?

```css
.figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

.figure-img {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.figure-caption {
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #636c72;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
                <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">1</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">2</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">3</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">4</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">5</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">6</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">7</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">8</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Я хочу что бы они у каждого был одинаковый отступ т.е. что бы все блоки были по центру. Неужели это только через flex можно сделать что то вроде `justify-content: flex-start;`, может в бутстрапе что то предусмотрено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно    `text-align: justify;` поможет

```css
.figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

.figure-img {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.figure-caption {
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #636c72;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.just {
  text-align: justify;
}

.just:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="just">
          <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">1</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">2</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">3</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">4</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">5</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">6</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">7</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <figure class="figure">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/65x65/00CED1/FFF/?text=65" alt="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-responsive">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><a href="#">8</a></figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, у меня точно такой же результат получился если вогнать блоки в список и задать ul `text-align-last: justify;` и li `display: inline; margin: 0 auto;`, в вашем же я не совсем понимаю, что делает блок в css `just:after` и почему именно в `after` ?

Comment: @PavelFedorov, если блокам задавать inline, то работает и без :after, а если inline-block (строчный снаружи, блочный внутри), то как раз нужен after для правильного отображения.